# Problem with RVIZ

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have two problems related with Rviz:

1. When I was using with my kinect using this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch) when I run rviz the window only showed a very small part of the image in the center, it wasn't like is shown in the tutorial, does anybody had the same problem, and know how to solve it?
2. After, I run this 'rosrun rviz rviz -d table_scene_mug_textured.vcg' and, well first it doesnt show anything on rviz, and well when I tried to launch my kinect again, the configuration of the settings of the rviz changed, and I cant find a way to put it back as it was, to see the images from the kinect. Again, does anybody know how to solve it?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32787/problem-with-rviz/) by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2012-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-08-18**:
Can you post a screenshot of what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can only say something to your second question:
The RViz display configurations are saved in a config file called "display_config" located in ~/.rviz/. This file is responsible for how your data are displayed, obviously.

In your case it seems like your display_config has been overwritten. This would mean you could not get back your old settings, unless you created a backup of the previous display_conf.

Maybe if you are lucky you can still find your old display_conf under File -> Recent configs.

If you want to display the camera data from your Kinect you could also manually add a new display to RViz ( In the display panel: Add -> Camera ) and set the topic of desired camera to your Kinect output topic ( In the display panel: Camera -> Image Topic ).

EDIT:
Oh well.... I have no idea why this question was shown to me in my unanswered questions, since it's already a year old...

---

Originally posted by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) with karma: 230 on 2013-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0